# ggplot 2 heatmap with varing axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I want to draw a heatmap, but the size of units on the x (and y) Axis should vary. Here an example code:

```
users = rep(1:3,3)
Inst = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3))
dens = rnorm(9)
n_inst = c(3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame( users, Inst, dens, n_inst )

1     1    A  1.2521487      3
2     2    A -0.1013088      3
3     3    A  1.5770535      3
4     1    B  1.1093957      2
5     2    B  1.1059166      2
6     3    B  0.6884662      2
7     1    C -0.3864710      1
8     2    C -1.0216373      1
9     3    C  0.4500778      1

z <- ggplot(df, aes(Inst, users)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = dens))
z + scale_x_discrete(breaks = n_inst)
```

[image]
So this draws a heatmap, but all units of `Inst` have the same size. I want `A` to be 3 times the width of `C` and `B` two times the width of `C`. So I want `n_inst` to give the width of units.

I tried scale_discret, but that doesn't do it

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Inst, users)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = dens, width=n_inst))
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you. What is the simular command for the y-axis?

Comment: it's height instead of width